# Run uglify-js in gulp task without gulp-uglify plugin

Tags: gulp, uglifyjs

I have a restriction of not using the `gulp-uglify` task. I want to create a gulp task that runs the following `uglify-js` command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs ./public/dist/js/myfile.js -o ./public/dist/js/myfile.min.js --comments='/customComments/'
```

Is there a way to do that without using the `gulp-uglify` task?

Comment: When you say `gulp-uglify` task, do you mean `gulp-uglify` package or do you have a gulp task called 'gulp-uglify'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Node.js-builtin [`child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to execute the command directly:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('default', function(done) {
  var uglifyjs = spawn('./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs', [
     './public/dist/js/myfile.js', 
     '-o', './public/dist/js/myfile.min.js', 
     "--comments='/customComments/'"
  ]);
  uglifyjs.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.error(data.toString());
  });
  uglifyjs.on('close', function(code) {
    if (code !== 0) {
      done('uglifyjs exited with code ' + code);
      return;
    }
    done();
  });
});
```